# How to import data into db using Feeds importers

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I created a [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) importer and when I try to run it, it gives this error

```
SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

What can cause this?

It's the header of `CSV` file that I'm trying

```
id,Title,LeakZip,Category,Type,LeakPhoto,Description,Username
```

and I'd mapped the same name in the importer as well

also in what `table` it puts the data in `database` ?

**Screen**
[image]

**CSV snippet**

```
id,Title,LeakZip,Category,Type,LeakPhoto,Description,Username
1,Angela Brown,"Hoboken,     NJ","Relationships","Negative","MuploadsMprofileM321267846956_sm.jpg","no scars or tattoos but she has a really bizarre hairline in the back shaped like the letter M. Last 3 digits of phone number : 265.", superUser
```

Comment: Screenshots go a long way to help out other people see what you see. That may be a great way to help communicate what you're trying to do.

Comment: is there any luck to import that data?
and in case if it successfully imported, then in what table it will store data in drupal db?

Comment: "Insert value list does not match column list" tells me something is not aligning correctly. Have you tried the CSV with and without the header row? Can you post a snippet of your CSV (changing or making up data if you need to... five rows of an example would help)? Post five rows or give a screen shot of the incoming data. You can get a lot of help from this site but people need to know a bit more. Have you tried first importing a smaller example CSV file that you created yourself?

Comment: @Richard: I'm importing first time in drupal, as new to Drupal, there is just one row(node/record) in the file at the moment.. I'll edit my question right now.
and I haven't tried it without headers.. I'll now that too

Comment: Yeah... I find that when something is not working, I have to stop and break it apart into small chunks. If you're using Feeds, look at this youtube Video for a good jump start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wasIAbfRls // Also which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I'm using drupal 7(according to changelog.txt in main drupal directory)

Comment: Feeds should offer a sample csv you can download. Try putting some of your data into the downloaded template and see if it uploads. Then, like Richard says, you'll have one piece of the bigger picture. You can add on gradually from there